# Python Locust stopped without error message, how should I check?

Tags: python, locust

I run locust using this command:

```
locust -f locustfile.py --no-web -c10 -r10 &> locust.log &
```

My understanding is all output (stdout, stderr) will goes to locust.log

However, when the program stopped without me triggering to stop, last  lines of locust.log is only the stat like below, no error message could be found:

```
 Name                                                          # reqs      # fails     Avg     Min     Max  |  Median   req/s
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GET /*******/**********/                                      931940     8(0.00%)      45      10   30583  |      23  101.20
 GET /**************/************/                             931504    14(0.00%)      47      11   30765  |      24  104.10
 GET /**************/***************/                             594 92243(99.36%)      30      12     549  |      23    0.00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Total                                                        1864038 92265(4.95%)                                     205.30
```

Since I didn't put number of request, the job should not stop forever.

Where and how should I check why the job is stopping?

Comment: Where you able to run it after this or it just stopped working altogether?

Comment: I was able to run it after it stopped